# Protractor Function Helper generate same thing

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have following files:

**protractor-functions.js**

```
function generateName() {
var names = ["Jewel", "Cesar", "Gita", "Denver", "Necole", "Oscar"];
  return names[Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)];
}

module.exports = {
  generateName: generateName()
};
```

**SignupTest.js**

```
var functions = require('../protractor-helpers/protractor-functions.js');
global.name1 = functions.generateName;
global.name2 = functions.generateName;
```

I get same name. If i move that function generateName() to the SignupTest.js it works perfectly fine.

I tried google, asking on protractor IRC but nothing really helpful. How can this be "fixed" to work like when I have function in test file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are not exporting function, but the generated value:

```
module.exports = {
  generateName: generateName() // you are calling function here
};
```

change it to this:

```
module.exports = {
  generateName: generateName
};
```

then you can call it like:

```
global.name1 = functions.generateName();
global.name2 = functions.generateName(); // it's now different
```

Comment: There you go. TIL, Thank you. Will accept answer in 10 minutes.